# smoothly varying smooth structures

Tags: smooth-manifolds, differential-topology

Can one vary smooth structures on $\mathbb R^4$ smoothly/continuously?

This question popped out of Ben's answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52191/is-a-fibration-in-algebraic-geometry-a-fibre-bundle/52195).

Comment: I assume you are aware of Taubes "Gauge theory on asymptotically periodic 4-manifolds", proving the existence of a uncountable family of smooth structures on $\mathbb{R}^4$, and subsequent work by Gompf "An Exotic Menagerie" proving the existence of a two-parameter family. What exactly would you mean by "smoothy" or "continuously" in this case?

Comment: @Kelly: I am aware of the first result you mention, bot not the second. You should add an answer! By smooth/continuous family I had in mind a smooth map $M\to N$ such that the fibers are non-diffeomorphic copies of $\mathbb R^4$; for *continuous*, I don't know what I mean, really :)

Comment: @Mariano: Probably you mean not just a smooth map $M\to N$ but a smooth submersion (as in Ryan's answer). That gives smooth structures to the fibers.

Comment: @Mariano: I'm not sure how to construct the submersion. Maybe I am missing something obvious?

Comment: Looks like this thread withered on the vine, but, in case anyone is interested: The $L_t$ of Theorem 9.4.10 in Gompf and Stipsicz could be used as a one-parameter family of exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$ and the construction in Theorem 9.4.16(a) in the same book could be able to be used for a two parameter family.

Comment: @Kelly: it has not withered! Can you add that as an answer?

Answer (score 9):

Yeah, sure.  A $1$-parameter family of smooth structures on a topological manifold $M$ can be taken to be a smooth structure on $M \times I$ such that the projection map $M \times I \to I$ is a submersion.  Similarly for higher families.

To relate it to your comments on Ben's thread, you can (apparently) find a $1$-parameter family of smooth structures on $\mathbb R^4$ such that all pairs of fibres $\mathbb R^4 \times \{a\}$ and $\mathbb R^4 \times \{b\}$ for all $a \neq b$ are not diffeomorphic.

That 2nd paragraph is really Larry Siebenmann talking. I don't believe I've ever seen such a construction.

Comment: How does that play along the fact that on $\mathbb R^5$ there is only one smooth structure?

Comment: (By the way: my intuition regarding smooth structures is simply non-existent... I may be asking something silly!)

Comment: @Mariano: I guess in that case the "strange" thing would be the projection itself, not the smooth structure on $\mathbb{R}^5$. (my intuition about smooth structures is nonexistent as well, though..)

Comment: @Ryan: For the required result in the second paragraph, couldn't you use the $L_t$ of Theorem 9.4.10 of Gompf and Stipsicz?