# Do exotic smooth structures on $\mathbb{R}^4$ vary smoothly?

Tags: differential-topology

Is the two-parameter family of exotic smooth structures on $\mathbb{R}^4$
constructed by Taubes and Gompf a smooth family? In other words, is there a submersion $p:V→\mathbb{R}_+\times\mathbb{R}_+$ of $C^∞$-manifolds such that $p^{−1}(s,t)=\mathbb{R}^4_{(s,t)}$ for every $(s,t)$? The original paper by Taubes only claims the existence of this two-parameter family of mutually non-isomorphic structures, I couldn't glean the stronger smoothness property from it.

Comment: I see that a very similar question was asked quite a while a go: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52250/smoothly-varying-smooth-structures,

but I'm not convinced the answer given there is as simple as that: a family indexed by a continuum is not the same thing as a continuous (let alone smooth) family. In fact, the putative manifold $V$ from my question would be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^6$, which has a *unique* smooth structure (by $h$-cobordism) -- so there must be something nontrivial going on.

Comment: This may not directly answer your question, but Kelly Davis in the comments to [MO52250](https://mathoverflow.net/q/52250) did point to some theorems in Gompf and Stipsicz that seem relevant. I can't follow all the details, but it seems that the infinite families of varying smooth structures $L_t$ or $R_t$ respectively from their Theorems 9.4.10 and 9.4.12 can be seen as open subsets of $R\times \mathbb{R}_+$, where $R$ is an exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$, which gives them the structure of smooth submersions.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine You're absolutely right! Indeed, taking $R$ to be one of those exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$'s, with $h:\mathbb{R}^4\to R$ a homeomorphism, and letting $I$ be an appropriate open interval, let
$$U=\{(t,x)\in I\times R | \|h^{-1}(x)\|<t\}.$$
Then the projection $U\to I$ is a submersion whose fibers are mutually non-diffeomorphic exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$'s. Moreover, since $U$ is 5-dimensional and contractible, it is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^5$, while $I$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. So in the end we have a submersion $p:\mathbb{R}^5\to\mathbb{R}$ with non-diffeomorphic fibers.

Comment: While this doesn't answer my original question, it does give me a counterexample I had in mind.

Comment: In 2018 I asked a similar question: Does there exist a smooth 5-manifold W that is homeomorphic to R^4 × [0, 1], such that if π : W → [0, 1] is the map to the 2nd coordinate, then for each t ∊ [0, 1] its inverse image M_t by π is an exotic smooth R^4, such that s ≠ t implies that M_s and M_t are not diffeomorphic?